# how to save image to client side C or JavaScript or ActiveX

Tags: c#, javascript, activex

i need to save an image file to client side ,, with out prompting the save,open,cancel dialog , or any similar thing , after long searching i heard that will this will be done only by ActiveX. 
please note that the website is on minimum security and its LocalSite and trusted site

Comment: I need to do the same with a text file .

Comment: Is this question still waiting for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You've heard correctly.  Even with ActiveX controls may be severely limited.  As well -- depending on client OS and security settings -- the control may need to be signed by a trusted Certificate Authority. (You can create one on your network, but how to do that and configure the client correctly are a questions for [server fault.](https://serverfault.com/))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this can solve your problem, but a copule of days ago I found this utility: http://downloadify.info. That's solution which is mix of flash app and jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily by creating a FireBreath plugin; FireBreath makes it relatively easy to create plugins that work both as ActiveX Controls (IE) and NPAPI plugins (firefox). You're right that ActiveX controls are going to be the only way to do it.

http://firebreath.org